# C# BeginSend fails after a while with no exception

Tags: c#, sockets

I am writing a client/server program using C# winsock classes. The multi-threaded server (1 thread per client connection) sends small chunks of data to clients. For performance reason I try to use BeginSend instead of Send. It seems to be working fine. The only problem I am encountering is that every a few hours the BeginSend stops sending data and the client has to reconnect to receive more data. So I tried to add the EndSend callback on the server and problem still remains. On the client side I am only using Receive instead of BeginReceive and I am not using semaphores in the server code. The code is very straight forward.  One thing I do notice is that there seems to be idle client connections on the server and I wonder if it is caused by deadlock.  Does anyone has an idea why this is so? Thanks a lot!

Here is the code that did the actuall send:

```
    protected virtual void SendMessage(Socket socket, byte[] message)
    {
        try 
        {
            if (socket.Connected)
            {
                _StateObject state = new _StateObject();

                state.socket = socket;
                state.nBytes = message.Length;

                socket.BeginSend(message, 0, message.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), state);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SocketErrorEventArgs e = new SocketErrorEventArgs();
            e.ex = ex;
            if (SocketBeginSendError != null) SocketBeginSendError(null, e);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            _StateObject state = (_StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket s = state.socket;

            int nBytesActuallySent = s.EndSend(ar);

            if (nBytesActuallySent != state.nBytes)
            {
                SocketErrorEventArgs e = new SocketErrorEventArgs();
                e.nBytes1 = state.nBytes;
                e.nBytes2 = nBytesActuallySent;
                if (SocketIncompleteSendError != null) SocketIncompleteSendError(null, e);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SocketErrorEventArgs e = new SocketErrorEventArgs();
            e.ex = ex;
            if (SocketEndSendError != null) SocketEndSendError(null, e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is virtually impossible to comment on in the absence or information about the network usage. For example, if the socket is unused for large amounts of time, the socket itself can silently die without reporting as such - this is not uncommon. We also can't see how you are sending: are you sending multiple times on a single socket without waiting for the first send to finish, for example. You *might* also want to try the overlapped IO API, aka `SendAsync` - however, by itself this shouldn't change anything - the first thing to do is to understand the problem. Needs more context, IMO.

Comment: Also: if you are using `BeginSend`, why do you have 1 thread per connection at the server? that seems odd to me (for the record, I would say that you *shouldn't* have 1 thread per connection). But again: any chance we can see any of this send code?

Comment: How exactly does BeginSend 'stop sending data'? Do you get an exception and if yes, what is it? Include native error code for SocketException.